# How to generate a whole number between 0-2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok so this is the code:

```
    var i = prompt('Rock, Paper or scissors?');
var b = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
```

Now, I need to generate (Correct me if I'm wrong please) a number between 0-2. My idea is (Well, was) this:

```
var i = prompt('Rock, Paper or scissors?');
var b = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
document.write(Math.random(0, 2));
var c = //the code I can't figure out
document.write(b[c]);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)` so `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`!

Answer (score 2):

Do it the following way `Math.floor(Math.random()*3) ie Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1))`

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random()*3));
```